# When moving multiple files in windows, when does it change the reference and when does it actually move the files?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, filesystems, file-transfer, copy-paste

I've noticed this inconsistent behavior:
Sometimes when moving multiple files, it would execute immediately, and other times, it would take some time and display a progress bar.

1. How can you know in advance which type of move will occur (copy vs. reference move)?
2. How can you set this behavior in advance, to move just the reference and not the file locations on disk.

Are these behaviors per OS, that is do they differ amongst windows versions? I've generally noticed that this behavior is more likely to occur on Vista, that is if you move a file to a new folder, it will actually delete it from its original location and paste it in the new one rather than just telling the OS it can now be accessed from a different folder.

Comment: are you copying files to/from the same disk?  or to another disk?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the OS tries to do the task as fast as it can:

When You copy, it will always have to write a copy of the file on the disk in another location.

When You move a file, it depends of the circumstances:

If You move to another partition/HDD/network location, it will also have to physically copy the fragments of the file. Note that this will take usually a bit longer than copying since moving files in this way will result a copy from point A to point B; after it has been *copied* to B, than it will be deleted from point A.

If You move a file(s) on the same partition, only in this case will it be faster. That's because the data itself is not moving, only the entries in the file allocation table become modified.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your answer, it's usually the simplist type of move, that is, it is on the same partition and it still manually cuts/pastes and shows a progress bar.

Comment: @Michael - Did I answer your question? If yes, You can accept it as an answer. If you have further questions, feel confident to ask.